# echo most recent folder in directory php?

Tags: php, html

I've tried this code, but it displays ALL folders in a given directory.

```
<?php $dir = './folder';$ffs = scandir($dir); foreach($ffs as $ff){ if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){ if(strpos($ff, '.')) {} else { $ff = ucfirst($ff); echo "<a href='../subjects/" . strtolower($ff) . "'>".$ff.'</a><br>'; } } } echo '</ol>'; }?>
```

How would I use PHP to echo the most recent FOLDER in a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the last entry of the filelist. You dont need to iterate over it

```
<?php 
    $dir = './folder';
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    if (is_array($ffs)) {
        $name_of_last_file = $ffs[count($ffs) - 1];
        if ($name_of_last_file != ".." && $name_of_last_file != "..") {
            echo "<a href='../subjects/" . strtolower($name_of_last_file) . "'>". $name_of_last_file .'</a><br>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>'; 
}?>
```

you should also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php to make sure the inserted string is save to use in HTML